# Outlook web add-in token autentication failure for on-premise exchange

Tags: oauth-2.0, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I use `Office.js`'s `getCallbackTokenAsync` to load the token to pass to the backend.

In the backend, I use EWS to retrieve the email data. Here is how I perform the authentication.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl); //retrieved from getCallbackTokenAsync
service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(ewsToken);// retrieved from getCallbackTokenAsync
```

It works well in exchange online enviroment. However when tested in on-premise exchange server, I got this authentication error:

```
Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Stack Trace:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
```

I then found this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/authentication-and-ews-in-exchange) says the Oauth2 authentication is only for exchange online. I guess I need to use this NTLM (Exchange on-premises only).

The major reason I use EWS instead of Graph or Rest is it supports on-premise server more naturally. So should I change the authentication here? I certainly do not want to ask user for username and password.

Or is there anything I need to do(maybe custom configuration) to make the on-premise exchange server support token authentication?

Comment: You could use Exchange user identity token, For more information, please refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authentication#exchange-user-identity-token

Comment: @AlinaLi Entity token is probably for SSO, if directly pass in as a replacement of call back token, the authentication will fail.